# How to switch subdomain with root domain and redirect traffic?

Tags: customization

I want to move subdomain to root, and create a new root. I have root.com. I want to move it to sub.root.com and install a new Wordpress intall at root.com. Any idea how I redirect the traffic from root to sub.root without affecting the new site? Or do I just have to move, wait for the search engines to redirect and then install the new copy on root.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all old inner pages to the new ones using `.htaccess` with HTTP header 301, but remember not to duplicate on the new site these parts of old URLs which goes after the old domain name (like `/new-page-1/` in the example below).

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /old-page-1/ httр://sub.domain.tld/new-page-1/
Redirect 301 /old-page-2/ httр://sub.domain.tld/new-page-2/
```

You can't do this with the main page. And you'll have to wait a week or more for search engines to reindex everything.